# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'IntVar'

Tags: python, variables, math, tkinter, typeerror

When I call the method `set_length()` I get the error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'IntVar'
```

How do I fix this and simply perform the math operation?

```
class Section:

    def __init__(self, id, bpm, bars, reps, num_tracks):
        self.id = id
        self.bpm = IntVar()
        self.bpm.set(bpm)
        self.bars = IntVar()
        self.bars.set(bars)
        self.reps = IntVar()
        self.reps.set(reps)
        self.num_tracks = num_tracks
        self.tracks = {}
        self.length = IntVar()
        self.length.set(bars * 4 / bpm * 60)

    def bpm_change(self, value):
        self.bpm = value
        print(str(self.bpm))
        self.set_length()

    def bars_change(self, value):
        self.bars = value
        print(str(self.bars))
        self.set_length()

    def set_length(self):
        self.length = (self.bars * 4 / self.bpm * 60)
```

Comment: use `self.bpm.get()` And use `self.bpm.set(value)` in place of `self.bpm = value`

Comment: Would you care to look back at my answer for your previous question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `self.bpm.get()` and `self.bars.get()` to get `int` values.

BTW: use `self.bpm.set(value)` , `self.bars.set(value)` and `self.length.set(value)` in place of `self.bpm = value`, `self.bars = value` and `self.length = value`